# Custom cursor gets stuck

Tags: javascript, html, css

Managed to get work a custom cursor with blend mode on the website but when i go to a link (About or a project) the cursor stops working and i don't know why is happening, any clues?

Here's the link to my website [www.2xv.work](http://www.2xv.work)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always check your console when debugging! In this case, it gives you all you're looking for.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '$bigBall' has already been declared`

It appears that `$bigBall` is being redeclared even though it was initially declared as a `const`. Declare `$bigBall` as `let`. That should fix your issue.

I'm willing to bet that `$smallBall`, and perhaps `$hoverables`, will give you the same issue as well.

```js
let $bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--big');
let $smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor__ball--small');
let $hoverables = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable');
```

Comment: That didn't fixed it, but somehow using the custom html console (running on cargo.site) did the trick and now is working, but hoverable class, to make the circle bigger when hover ain't working, have a clue?